# completely failed to read post data in vertx route handler chain - tried all ways no success

Tags: groovy, vert.x, httphandler

i'm running a gradle build with vertx web.  my library dependecies include

```
   // for mock API serving https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/vertx-core
    compile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-core', version: '3.5.3'
    compile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-web', version: '3.5.3'
```

so in my groovy script code i do this

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx()
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer()  
...
```

I then declare a route to catch all requests on resource and process the request and form a response - trying to keep it simple - just return simple string as response

```
Router allRouter = Router.router(vertx)

allRouter.route ( "/api/now/table/incident")
        .handler(BodyHandler.create())
        .blockingHandler { routingContext ->

    def request  = routingContext.request()
    HttpMethod method = request.method()

    def response = routingContext.response()
    response.putHeader ("content-type", "text/plain")

    def uri = routingContext.request().absoluteURI()
    switch (method) {
        case HttpMethod.GET:
            println "processing a resource GET on uri : $uri "
            response.end ("(GET) howdi will")
            break

        case HttpMethod.POST:

            String bodyEnc = routingContext.getBodyAsJson().encodePrettily()

            println "processing a resource POST on uri : $uri"

            println "post request received post data : " + bodyEnc

            response.end ("(POST) howdi will")
            break
    }

}
```

I create a handler for BodyHandling, before the general handler in the route.

Then I start the server with the route

```
server.requestHandler(allRouter.&accept)
server.listen(8081, "localhost")
```

works all fine for a get request from postman.

when i use a post request with a request body data - the service hangs and i have to cancel - it never gets to the switch statement.  All that happens in the console when i issue the post is

```
23:30:16.455 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 32768
23:30:16.455 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
23:30:16.455 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
23:30:16.455 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
23:30:16.478 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
23:30:16.482 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@51d486
```

This is the nearest to being a related topic [enter link description here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/402)

I have tried this countless ways now, set bodyHandler inside the request when i get it etc - can't get it to work.

my postman post looks like this - where the headers are set to Content-Type application/json, Content-Length is 296 bytes (length of bytes in utf16), and Accept is text/plain to receive simple response

[image]
The documentation is just not clear.  Blown 12 hours trying to crack this.

Does any one know exactly how one should get the post data on a request when using vertx web please

Comment: hmmm... could it be that the route is being handled before the `BodyHandler` can be installed? have you tried installing the router before creating the route? if not, try removing the existing line to create the `BodyHandler` and adding `allRouter.route.().handler(BodyHandler.create())` just before `allRouter.route( "/api/now/table/incident")`.

Comment: I tried that - with same problem.  But i had a brain wave overnight in my sleep as you do.  The postman was hanging and i didnt get to the blocking handler correctly.  so i had originally assesed the post request context block as reqBody.getBytes(charset.forname("utf16")).size() - which was 296 bites.  so i just went simple and changed to reqBody.getBytes().size() which is 147 bytes.  When i changed postman to say content-length was 147 length instead and it started to work .

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though my problem was the size of bytes being sent.  I had calculated the bytes of the reqBody string as 296 bytes (using UTF16 charset), and set this into the Postman request.

So the vertx server was trying to read that many when processing the body and hanged.  When I just did reqBody.getBytes().size - effectively UTF8, this returned 147 bytes.  When I changed the content-length to this in postman, it started to work.

There is a timing issue in where you setup the BodyHandler.  I tried this is tin the switch case, and it fails with request has already been read.

However neither of these seem to work successfully.

option 1 : ' create body handler before the route (path) call'

```
allRouter.route().handler(BodyHandler.create())

//now try and setup the route for API path interception
allRouter.route ( "/api/now/table/incident")
        .blockingHandler { routingContext -> ...
```

option 2 : 'chain the handlers but put the Body Handler first'

```
//now try and setup the route for API path interception, followed by body handler
allRouter.route ( "/api/now/table/incident")
        .handler(BodyHandler.create())
        .blockingHandler { routingContext ->...
```

This was setting the content-length, assuming UTF16 for internal byte size that was the real problem.  Now back to trying to complete what I set out to do.